# Mapping XML array in JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb

I want to map an XML array using JAXB. The array object is created. But the array is not populated.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++ XML array +++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<ns1:intArray xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
    <int>9864</int>
    <int>7291</int>
    <int>6249</int>
    <int>679</int>
</ns1:intArray>
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++ JAXB class +++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
@XmlRootElement
public class IntArray {

    private int[] array;

    @XmlElement(name = "int")
    public int[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++ package-info.java +++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
namespace = "http://www.example.org",
xmlns = {@XmlNs(prefix = "ns1",
    namespaceURI = "http://www.example.org")})
package com.xml.test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++ Main.java +++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    File xml = new File("/media/sda3/array.xml");

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(IntArray.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    IntArray obj = (IntArray) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

    int[] arr = obj.getArray();
    System.out.println(arr); // null

}
```

Why is the array not populated with xml data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have specified `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` the `int` elements should be namespace qualified just like the root element.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: since I have specified elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, the int elements also should be namespace qualified.  Therefore since I have not used a prefix for the int elements, they should belong to the default namespace. Thanks !!!